# Cakelog is writing to multiple files, but I want it to write to only the one I specify

Tags: cakephp, logging, cakephp-2.2

I want to log payment gateway errors in `payment.log`. So add this to `bootstrap`:

```
CakeLog::config('payment', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'file' => 'payment',
));
```

and when a problem occurred:

```
CakeLog::write('payment', 'The is a problem!');
```

but, the above command will log `This is a problem!` in both `payment.log` and `error.log`, while log into first file is enough.

Also, if any other problems occurred in other controllers (like `users`), it will log into both files. while it should just log in `error.log`

(I mean payment errors should log into `payment.log` and any other problems should write into `error.log`)

Where's the mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the scopes option in the [config](http://api.cakephp.org/class/cake-log#method-CakeLogconfig) maybe?

```
CakeLog::config('payments', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'scopes' => array('payment', 'order')
));
```

Then you need to specify the scope where you want to write to:

```
CakeLog::write('warning', 'Stuff is broken here', 'payment');
```

It may take some fiddling to get it just right, but this should help.